# How come I can implicitly but not explicit cast?

Tags: java

I was testing around with Java and noticed that casting "physically" changes properties of an object. I don't quite understand what actually happens inside Java when casting is used, but I did notice this:

Here is my Super class `InstanceVariable`:

```
package inheritance;

public class InstanceVariable {
    public int x = 1;
}
```

Here is a class that inherits from it:

```
package inheritance;

public class InstanceVariable1 extends InstanceVariable {

    public int x = 100;
    public static int y = 2;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InstanceVariable1 one = new InstanceVariable1();
        InstanceVariable two = new InstanceVariable1();
        System.out.println(one.x + " " + two.x);
        one = (InstanceVariable) one; //This is illegal
    }
}
```

First of all, the instance variable that were instantiated are overriden by the child class. And secondly, I can implicitly cast the super class (that is `InstanceVariable`) to `two`, but for some reason, I cannot explicitly cast it to `one`? What is the reason for this?

Comment: Because one is _more_ than an InstanceVariable.

Comment: All figs are tree but all trees are not figs.. Think something on these lines

Comment: That explicit cast doesn't make any sense.  You could do this, however: `InstanceVariable one = new InstanceVariable1();`.  Your variable doesn't hold an InstanceVariable, it holds an InstanceVariable1 type.  If you want any explanations to be more clear, you might want to use better class names.  Your example is analagous to this: `ArrayList<String> list = (List<String>) new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: What I mean is that, how is the implicit cast of `two` legal but the explicit cast of `one` is illegal? They are both `InstanceVariable1` objects

Comment: The cast is OK but the assignment isn't.

Comment: On two, you are referring to the InstanceVariable1 class by its interface.  That is perfectly rational.  You aren't comparing apples to apples.

Comment: Let's assume `InstanceVariable` = `Animal` and `InstanceVariable1` = `Dog` and then think about it: is every dog an animal? (e.g. `InstanceVariable two = new InstanceVariable1();`) And is every animal a dog? (e.g. `one = (InstanceVariable) one`)

Comment: Is it because the immutable nature of Java objects? as in I am trying to reassign and change the object into something else? In that case, what happens in the implicit cast case?

Comment: Ok, but I'm wondering why the implicit cast is even allowed then

Comment: Well, in the world where I came from i can say: every dog is also an animal ... ;). So why should that cast fail?

Comment: Ok, using the analogy `InstanceVariable` = `Animal` and `InstanceVariable1` = `Dog`, then `one` is assigned as a `Dog`. That makes sense, we cannot cast `Dog` to `Animal`.  But for variable `two`, it is implicitly cast from a `Dog` to an `Animal`, and that case succeeds

Comment: Again, there is nothing wrong with the cast. The problem is the assignment where you assign an `Animal` to a variable of type `Dog`.

Comment: @Henry, does the assignment fail for the same reason that: `int x = 1;` then: `x = "Hi";` fails

Comment: *"That makes sense, we cannot cast Dog to Animal"* No, this is not correct. You _can_ cast a dog to an animal. But you can't cast an animal to a dog, because since it is an "animal" it could already be a `Cat` instance refered by that variable, so you would end up casting a cat to a dog. And yes, a "general" animal would fail as well.

Comment: Ok, but where am I casting a `Animal` to a `Dog`?

Comment: You are not casting, you assign an `Animal` to a `Dog` variable. In this case a cast would even work because the object IS a `Dog`. e.g: `one = (InstanceVariable1)(InstanceVariable)one;` is OK.

Comment: This is ok as well: `two = (InstanceVariable)one;`